# New Facebook iOS SDK posting to feed with dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa, facebook-graph-api

The new facebook SDK is out...

this was used in the old SDK for status sharing

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
                               @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                               @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
                               @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
                               @"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
                               nil];

// Invoke the dialog
[self.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

whats the equivalent in the new SDK

Answer (score 3):

It looks very similar to what you have.  From the SDK guide:

```
self.postParams =
        [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
         @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
         @"https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
         @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
         @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
         @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
         nil];
```

Posting the message no longer requires delegates and instead uses blocks:

```
   [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                             parameters:self.postParams
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                          // Handle Success/Failure

                      }];
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/

Comment: yes, but this directly shares, in the old sdk a dialog like this was presented https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/cfs-ak-snc6/84979/436/306608846104444-/feed-dialog-iphone-1.png how to do it, without manually creating a view controller (isnt there something build in?)

Answer (score 0):

You may have found the answer by now, but have you looked into https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/